# Showing pop up View when calling redirect in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Scenario :**

The scenario is if user press tab after entering AWB No. which he previously temporary saved, all ex values must populate on run time.

**Problem :**

Everything is working fine but view which is populated with ex values is opening as a pop up.

[image: It's working fine just opening a pop kind of view I want to refresh the current view only]

**JavaScript for onchange**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#AWBNO").change(function () {
    var AWB = $("#AWBNO").val();
    var IGMa = $("#IGMa").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/IMPORTAWBs/AuthenticatingAWB")?awb=' + AWB + '&igm=' + IGMa,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {

            if (result == "Authenticated AWB!") {
                                    $("input:disabled").removeAttr('disabled');
                                    $("select:disabled").removeAttr('disabled');
                                    $("#AWBNO").removeAttr('disabled');
                                    $("#process").removeAttr('disabled');
                                    $("#PAGENO").focus();
            }
            else {
                                    $("#dialog").dialog({ appendTo: "#AWBNO" }).html(result);
                                    $("input:enabled").prop('disabled', true);
                                    $("select:enabled").prop('disabled', true);
                                    $("#AWBNO").removeAttr('disabled');
                                    $("#process").removeAttr('disabled');
                                    $("#AWBNO").focus();
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr, stats, errorMessage) {
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    });
});
```

**Code for sending instance to Edit Method:**

```
 public ActionResult AuthenticatingAWB(string awb, string igm)
    {
        if (igm != null && awb != null)
        {
            string igmNO = igm;
            var IgmNo = context.IMPORTAWBs.Where(f => f.IGMNO == igmNO && f.AWBNO == awb).FirstOrDefault();
            var awbPart = context.IMPORTAWBs.Where(f => f.AWBNO == awb && f.IGMNO != igm && (f.SHIPMENTTYPE == "Part" || f.SHIPMENTTYPE == "Short")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (awbPart == null)
            {

                if (awb != null)
                {

                    if (IgmNo == null)
                    {
                        return CheckAuthenticatedAWB(awb);
                    }
                    return Content("Duplicate Airway Bill Provided against above IGM No. , please verify again.");

                }
                else
                {
                    IsAuthencatedAWB = false;
                    return Content("Invalid Airway Bill Number Provided, Please verify it according to formula.");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", awbPart);
            }
        }
        return Content(null);
    }
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id,IMPORTAWB RunTimeImportAWBInstance)
    {
        var awbno = TempData["AWBNO"];
        var igmno = TempData["IGMNO"];
        if (awbno != null && igmno != null)
        {
            var importawb = context.IMPORTAWBs.Where(x => x.AWBNO == awbno && x.IGMNO == igmno).FirstOrDefault();
            var deliveryInfo = context.DELIVERYINFOes.Where(f => f.AWBNO == importawb.AWBNO).FirstOrDefault();
            if (deliveryInfo != null)
            {
                DeliveryInfo(importawb, deliveryInfo);
            }
            DetailSessionHandleClass = context.IMPORTAWBDETAILs.Where(f => f.AWBNO == importawb.AWBNO).ToList();
            ViewBagList();
            ViewBag.PossibleIGM = context.IMPORTMANIFIESTs.Where(f => f.IGMNO == importawb.IGMNO).FirstOrDefault();
            CargoEntities._olderInstancea = importawb;
            return View(importawb);
        }

        else {
            var importawb = (RunTimeImportAWBInstance == null) ? context.IMPORTAWBs.Where(x => x.AWBId == id).FirstOrDefault() : RunTimeImportAWBInstance;
            var deliveryInfo = context.DELIVERYINFOes.Where(f => f.AWBNO == importawb.AWBNO).FirstOrDefault();
            if (deliveryInfo != null)
            {
                DeliveryInfo(importawb, deliveryInfo);
            }
            DetailSessionHandleClass = context.IMPORTAWBDETAILs.Where(f => f.AWBNO == importawb.AWBNO).ToList();
            ViewBagList();
            ViewBag.PossibleIGM = context.IMPORTMANIFIESTs.Where(f => f.IGMNO == importawb.IGMNO).FirstOrDefault();
            CargoEntities._olderInstancea = importawb;
            return View(importawb);
        }
```

Comment: Is there some javascript attached to the control. You often can see this with Visual Event Plugin if you're not sure.

Comment: @Kaido yes the starting point of scenario is based on Jquery which track ("#AWBId").onchange() and calls controller method AuthenticatingAWB() written above but here I think javascript is not directly interfering may be I there is problem of actionresult or redirectaction not sure.

Comment: Can you include the javascript and the callback for the post? I think it is involved

Comment: @Kaido I updated my question have a look.

Comment: Yeah that particular function doesn't look related. So the redirect to Edit occurs and then the content of edit is what was expected, except the styling of that panel with "Cities, Airline,.." is unexpected?

Comment: It was expected but pop up version was not expected it must refresh the current tab with values, but it's popping up another edit view.

Comment: Sorry man, there are still lots of things it could be. I'm thinking something in the Edit View design but could be javascript, code or css.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple, the pop up is being displayed because your code is written to display that:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ appendTo: "#AWBNO" }).html(result);
```

The code above picks up `#dialog` element uses `jQuery dialog()` method appends it to element `#AWBNO` and then `.html()` method changes the mark up of that dialog to the variable result.

According to your `AuthenticatingAWB` Action the content that you can expect in your pop up is:

1. `Duplicate Airway Bill Provided against above IGM No. , please
   verify again`
2. `Invalid Airway Bill Number Provided, Please verify it according to formula.`
3. `RedirectToAction("Edit", awbPart);`

The content you have posted screenshots for is because of the `RedirectToAction("Edit", awbPart);` when it returns the new page it's mark up is added to element `#dialog' hence the result is in pop up.

**The official documentation:**

- [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [.html( htmlString )](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)